# Who is he? Who he is?

Tags: colloquial-language

Can we say ...

> "Do you know who is he?"

To me, it sounds very unnatural and grammatically incorrect. 
Though, I think we can say ...

> "Do you know? Who is he?"

in conversation.

Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

You have it right. As a single question, we would write:

> Do you know **who he is**? (not, Do you know <strike>who is he</strike>?)

However, the way you have punctuated these six words makes the wording acceptable in your second example. The first question ("Do you know?") is a lead-in to the second ("Who is he?").

When written that way, I imagine the speaker being rather excited. Perhaps there is a lot of buzz in the street as a celebrity is walking by. Someone might excitedly say to a friend, "Do you know? Who is he?"

I think in a more calm and collected state of mind, the question order is likely to be reversed:

> Who is he? Do you know?

Answer (score 5):

You might try thinking of the pattern you ask about as follows:

> Do you know  {interrogative word} {assertion}?

The clause that states the {assertion} uses normal word-order, subject...verb.

Do you know who {he is} ?

Do you know when {the train arrives}?

Do you know why {the library is closed today}?

Do you know where {my car keys went}?

Do you know how {this knot is tied}?

Answer (score 3):

> [1] *Do you know* [*who is he*]*?*
>
> [2] *Do you know* [*who he is*]*?*

The subject-auxiliary inversion in [1] is wrong in most varieties of English, but [2] is fine.

The bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (indirect question). Unlike main clause interrogatives, there is normally no inversion in subordinate interrogatives.

The meaning can be glossed as: “*Do you know the answer to the question “Who is he?”’*